# Any body know what the explanation of this line code “for fold, (trn_, val_) in enumerate(kf.split(X=df))”

Tags: python, for-loop, sklearn-pandas

#Training data is in a CSV file called train.csv
df = pd.read_csv(“train.csv”)

```
#we create a new column called kfold and fill it with -1
df[“kfold”]=-1

#the next step is to randomize the rows of the data
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

#initiate the kfold class from model_selection module
kf = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=5)

#fill the new kfold column
for fold, (trn_, val_) in enumerate(kf.split(X=df)):
    df.loc[val_, ‘kfold’] = fold
```

Comment: Which meaning do you want, the python meaning, the syntax? or the Machine Learning meaning?

Comment: Which parts of the line in question do yo uunderstand, and which specific piece(s) are unclear? `model_selection.KFold`, `enumerate`, `kf.split()`? Have you tried checking the outputs and documentation for each step? The more specific you can be with your question ,the more specific the answers can be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given code, the kf.[split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)(X=df) method takes the 'df' dataframe as the input and splits the indices of the df dataframe into train and test sets. The split() method returns a list of indices, one for train set and another one for test set, in the form of tuple (trn_, val_). In addition, the split() method is wrapped in the [enumerate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/)() method, which acts as a counter to the split() iterable and returns enumerate objects. As there will be 5 folds returned from the split() method, the enumerate indices will range from 0-4, indicating the i-th fold. So, the 'enumerate(kf.split(X=df))' statement returns 'fold, (trn_, val_)'.

For every returned enumerate object from the split() method, which contains a counter index (fold) and a tuple of train and test indices (trn_, val_), the index (fold) is assigned as the value of the 'kfold' column, where the rows are in the 'val_' indices list.

That means the value of 'kfold' column is the i-th fold the respective row/sample is assigned as the validation sample. For example, if df.loc[0, 'kfold'] = 2, it means that the row 0 sample of the df dataframe is assigned as part of the validation set when fold=2.